# Flex 4.5: Tree DisplayList

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I'm trying to make a Flex Tree Component display the children of a sprite in a hierarchical way.

Moreover, dragging the items on the FlexTree would resort and reparent the items. I have special Elements set as Folders. This would allow other elements to be added there as a children by dragging an element on the tree and dropping it there.

I have a failed attempt which works, but breaks when I try to add folders. Basically, it fails at reparenting the items by dragging and resorting folders and that D:

Does anyone know of a component or something which can do this, has anyone have created any of this or could anyone give me a clue?

Comment: How does it fail? How do you do the reparenting? If you do it carefully I don't see how removing and re-adding DisplayObjects would not work.

Comment: The problem is I can't figure out how to find which object I should add the dragged thing into. Basically, I am lost at the dragComplete thing. Folders have a children ArrayCollection, but I'm lost at what to do and how to find the data...

Comment: I still am having a hard time understanding what you want. A DisplayObjectContainer works as a folder, it allows you to add multiple levels of other DisplayObjects, but a DisplayObject may only be bound to one parent.

Comment: I am trying to represent that hierarchy on a Flex Tree component, so you can see the children of a certain sprite in a Tree structure, and also allowing the user to drag the childrens there to sort them and reparent them through folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did it is not use flash sprites for the layer management, but use a separate variable which holds the folder each element belongs to.

Then, the tree is created using that information and it's easier to modify it.